# How to write comments in prototxt files?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, protocol-buffers

I can't find how to write comments in **prototxt** files.

Is there any way to have comments in a prototxt file, how?

Thanks

Comment: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html (first link in google) has examples with comments

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can comment by adding the `#` char: everything in the line after that is a comment:

```
layer {
  name: "aLayerWithComments" # I picked this cool name by myself
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "someData" # this is the output of the layer below
  top: "someData" # same name means this is an "in-place" layer
}
# and now you can comment the entire line...
```