# How to ignore log print a unused layer in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have an prototxt as follows:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./train.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data_scale2"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data_scale2"
  top: "label_scale2"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./train_scale2.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
}
```

where the second layer contains the scale factor of 2 of the original data, I named it as `data_scale2`. During training, I just used the `data`,`label` and `data_scale2` without using `label_scale2`. Hence, when I run training, the value of `label_scale2` always printing in my terminal. How can I ignore this? This log looks like

```
I0302 18:01:57.356312 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221177: label_scale2 = 0
I0302 18:01:57.356314 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221178: label_scale2 = 0
I0302 18:01:57.356320 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221179: label_scale2 = 0
I0302 18:01:57.356324 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221180: label_scale2 = 0
I0302 18:01:57.356328 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221181: label_scale2 = 0
I0302 18:01:57.356329 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221182: label_scale2 = 0
I0302 18:01:57.356333 30995 solver.cpp:245]     Train net output #221183: label_scale2 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

**General solution:**
If you wan to silence a `"top"` layer you can use [`"Silence"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/silence.html) layer:

```
layer {
  type: "Silence"
  name: "silence_this_layer_for_me"
  bottom: "label_scale2"
}
```

And that's it! You won;t hear from `label_scale2` again

**A solution for HDF5Data**
Alternatively, you do not have to expose all `datasets` of an `hdf5` input. You can simply [comment out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37419537/1714410) the redundant `"top"`:

```
layer {
  name: "data_scale2"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data_scale2"
  # top: "label_scale2" 
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./train_scale2.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first solution using `Silence` worked but the second does not work. I commented it before but I got error `hdf5_data_layer.cpp:73] Check failed: hdf_blobs_[0]->num_axes() >= 1 (0 vs. 1) Input must have at least 1 axis.`

Comment: @user8264 that's odd. can you check the structure of your hdf5 file using `h5ls` shell util?

Comment: Yes. My hdf5 has two element `data_scale2` and `label_scale2`. However, I just used `data_scale2` for training. The full information is `/data_scale2 Dataset {1, 1, 56, 56} /label_scale2 Dataset {1, 1, 56, 56}`